# ImportError: cannot import name 'styles' from 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib, styles

The issue is in the title:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'styles' from 'matplotlib'
```

I have tried the recommended answers, I have used

```
sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

and

```
pip install --user --upgrade matplotlib
```

and still have the same error as before.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import styles

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
```

error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'styles' from 'matplotlib' 
 (/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py)
```

I have tried this with a few python versions in vs code (3.6.6, 3.7.6, 3.8.1) and Anaconda Spyder (which I believe is 3.7.x but I'm not sure which) and get the same error.

Any ideas or is Matplotlib styles not useable anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean 'style' instead of 'styles'?

```
from matplotlib import style
```